# How to expand three boolean brackets with three variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra

I know how can I exapand expression with two variables and two brackets, but how can I expand this:

$$(A ∧ B ∧ C) ∨ (D ∧ E ∧ C) ∨ (D ∧ B ∧ F)$$

In result should be 27 disjunctions and only three variables.

Comment: Use associativity of $\vee$ and $\wedge$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the first two terms like so:

$$[(A ∧ B ∧ C) ∨ (D ∧ E ∧ C)] ∨ (D ∧ B ∧ F)$$

Expand what is in $[\cdots]$ first, and then combine with the $\lor (D\land B\land F)$ term.

Technically speaking, $\lor$ is a binary operator, which means it takes two inputs, so the expression needs some kind of grouping symbols. However, we simplify notation by dropping the parentheses, similar to how we write $a+b+c$ and not worry about if it's $(a+b)+c$ vs $a+(b+c)$ in most contexts since they have the same value.